# ¿Como pasar el contenido de la fila selecciona al los TextBox con C#?

Tags: c#

tengo el siguiente código, con el evento KeyPress para al dar enter sobre una fila seleccionada, este me pase los datos a las cajas de texto.

```
    private void dgvistaFP_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
        {
            var frmc = Owner as FrmCuadre;
            try
            {
                if (dgvistaFP.SelectedRows.Count >= 1)
                {
                    frmc.txttipo.Text = dgvistaFP.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    frmc.txtNombrefp.Text = 
                    dgvistaFP.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    frmc.txtvalorfp.Focus();
                    this.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

Pero tengo el inconveniente que cuando hay más de una fila no me está pasando los datos en selección, si no, la fila que tiene por debajo de esta de la que esta seleccionada.

agradezco de antemano su apoyo y conocimiento.

Comment: Hola, la Comunidad agradeceria que si alguna de las respuestas dadas en tu pregunta es correcta o te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, marques estas como respondida, adicional esto te dara resputacion como usuario y en tu cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa, es que cuando presionas Enter salta a la línea siguiente y por eso estas capturando la fila posterior.

Debes usar un evento anterior a que este cambio se produzca, como por ejemplo `KeyDown`, con el cual puedes capturar los seleccionados y luego de eso saltará a la siguiente fila

```
private void dgvistaFP_KeyDown(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
           
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //e.Handled = true; //Con esto habilitado, no saltará a la siguiente fila
                
                
        if (dgvistaFP.SelectedRows.Count >= 1)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvistaFP.SelectedRows)
            {
                //aqui recorro una a una las filas seleccionadas
            }

            //esto me traería solo la primera fila seleccionada
            //DataGridViewRow primera = dgvistaFP.CurrentRow;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Yussef, con el Evento que me indicas, me funciono perfectamente, a lo requerido, muchas gracias su conocimiento ayuda a muchos.